# Is it possible to prevent cloudflare to cache my images?

Tags: wordpress, caching, cdn, cloudflare

I try to get an answer on the question if it is possible to prevent Cloudflare from caching my images.

The link to the files would be https://my-domain/wp-content/uploads/2019/*
The * on the end indicates that all what is in /2019/ should be ignored.

I read this post:https://www.itsupportguides.com/knowledge-base/tech-tips-tricks/how-to-exclude-wp-admin-from-cloudflare/ which is indicating that it is possible for http://my-domain/wp-admin/ but I'm not sure if it will also work for my uploads folder. See the last sentence in the image below.

[image]

I want this folder ignored because I'm using another cdn for my images.

Comment: What is the value to using 2 different CDNs?  The whole point of a CDN is edge caching technology.  If one of the CDNs has the edge servers and performance that you want, then why wouldn't you use it for both?  And I'm sure you could answer your question easily if you took the time to read the cloudflare documentation or did some basic research.

Comment: @Justin, thanks for your comment. I'm using Imgix for my images. That's a kind of special cdn especially for images. It is able to perform operations on the fly on images as well. Downside is that they don't cache other static sources like minified css, minified js, html and such. So I was thinking to use CloudFlare for all other stuff but images.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that with a [Page Rule](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/202775670-How-Do-I-Tell-Cloudflare-What-to-Cache-).

If a Page Rule is set to "Bypass Cache", then the resources that match that page rule will not be cached. Note that we will still act as a proxy, and our other performance features will still be active - content just won't be served from our cache and fetched from the origin directly.

Ryan